# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined - although jQuery is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm aware that this is a well discussed question, nevertheless I did not find any answer for my issue. I have the following code on a Wordpress page (inline, necessary for this project):

```
<script>
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.choosekurs').on('click', function() {
        $('textarea[name="textarea"]').text($(this).attr('data-attr-package')); 
     });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I also tried it the other way around:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    $('.choosekurs').on('click', function() {
        $('textarea[name="textarea"]').text($(this).attr('data-attr-package')); 
  });
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately I still get the same error. I can see jQuery being loaded in the footer (v3.6.0 as well as 3.3.2 migrate version), so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory. When you insert your code, jQuery has not been defined. You have to put that `script` after jQuery is loaded.

If you can't change where jQuery is defined, as you say in your comment to [Pat J's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/403117/208483), then insert your script in the `<footer>`.

Answer (score 0):

If the inline `<script>` is in the `<head>` or `<body>` of your page, and jQuery is loaded in the footer (ie, at the end), then jQuery *doesn't exist* when you're trying to run your jQuery code.

Either enqueue `jquery` to load in the header (ie, set the `$in_footer` parameter to `false`), or—the better option—use [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to properly load your script. This latter option will also let you define `jquery` as a dependency for your script.

Comment: Thanks you for the quick answer @Pat J - for this project I only have access to the Wordpress page, no editor, no ftp etc. Is there any other way to make this work?

Comment: Not that I can think of, I'm afraid. You don't want to load jQuery twice, as I suspect that'd have unintended consequences.